# ts-node cannot find a local file that exists

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I'm just trying to run `npx tsc && node dist` in the project directory with the following project structure:

```
project
|--dist
|--node_modules
|--src
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|--...
```

...and it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './dist'
```

I checked the dependencies, ran `npm install`, and also made sure that the path is correct. Is there anything wrong with my configuration? I honestly have no clue.

The following is my `tsconfig.json` btw:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Whats in dist? And why are you running `ts-node` there? Usually in `dist/` you will find the *output* of typescript, and you can run regular `node` to run Javascript.

Comment: @Evert Yes, ```dist``` contains the output of typescript and sorry, I am not running ```ts-node```, I'm running ```npx tsc && node dist```, which gives me the above error. I'll edit my question as well

Comment: Does `dist/index.js` exist?

Comment: @robertklep `dist/index.js` does exists although it doesn't do anything. This project only contains some classes/interfaces to be shared between my front-end and back-end for my other project.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen by running `node dist`? You typically don't pass a directory to Node, but a file.

Comment: @robertklep It gives me this exact error: ```node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '.../project/dist',``` and it gives me the same error when I run ```node dist/index.js``` which is very odd as I can see that they are clearly there :(